# Ergodic system, show an implication

Tags: ergodic-theory

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu,T)$ be a dynamic system in measure theory and $p\geq 1$. Show the implication $(1)\implies (2)$, whereat
> >     $$
> > (1)~~~~~\forall f\in L_{\mu}^p: f= f\circ T\implies f=\text{ const.}
> > $$
> >     $$
> > (2)~~~~~(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu,T)\text{ is ergodic}.
> > $$

I do not really know how to show that.

In another exercise I showed that $(2)$ is equivalent to $(3)$ whereat
$$
(3)~~~~~\forall A\in\mathfrak{A}: T^{-1}A\subset A\implies\mu(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}.
$$
So I take a $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ with $T^{-1}A\subset A$ and now have to show that $\mu(A)\in\left\{0,1\right\}$, assuming (1)?

Answer (score 0):

That (1) implies (2) follows from the definition of ergodicity (take $f$ the characteristic function of a measurable set).

For the converse, take $f$ a measurable function and define 
$$S(c):=\{x, f(x)\leqslant c\}.$$
The set $S(c)$ is measurable and invariant hence its measure is $0$ or $1$. Defining $c_0:=\inf\{c, \mu(S(c))=1\}$, we have that $f=c_0$ almost surely.

Comment: Is $\mu$ a probability measure?

Comment: I think so (take $A=\Omega$ in (3)).

Comment: If so, then I would make it this way in order to prove $(1)\implies (2)$: Consider $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ with $T^{-1}(A)\subset A$. Then $1_A$ is in $L_{\mu}^p$ for all $p\geq 1>$, because $1_A$ is measurable, because $A\in\mathfrak{A}$ and for $1\leq p<\infty$ it is $\int_{\Omega}\lvert 1_A\rvert^p\, d\mu=\mu(A)\leq\mu(\Omega)=1<\infty$. And for $p=\infty$, the essential supremum is $1<\infty$. Furthermore, $1_A=1_A\circ T$, because of $T^{-1}(A)\subset A$. So it follows: $1_A$ is constant (i.e. const =1 or constant =0 on whole $\Omega$). That means $\mu(A)=\mu(\Omega)=1$ or $\mu(A)=0$.

Comment: Is that proof okay?

Comment: And to your proof of $(2)\implies (1)$. You showed that $f$ is constant almost surely, but it is to show that f is constant.

Comment: Maybe you can show me in more details how from $(2)$ follows $(1)$? I do not manage it to show that.