# Ergodic: Show another implication

Tags: ergodic-theory

> > Let $(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu,T)$ be a dynamic system in measure theory and $p\geq 1$. Show that the following statements are equivalent:
> >     $$
> > (1)~~~~~(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu,T)\text{ is ergodic}\\(2)~~~~~\text{For any measurable function }f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}\text{ it is: }f=f\circ T\text{ a.s }\implies f=\text{const. a.s.}\\(3)~~~~~\forall f\in L_{\mu}^p: f=f\circ T\implies f=\text{const.}
> > $$

Here [Ergodic system, show an implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633798/ergodic-system-show-an-implication) I have shown $(3)\implies (1)$.
Here [Show: Ergodic implies $f=\text{const a.s.}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633653/show-ergodic-implies-f-textconst-a-s) I tried $(1)\implies (2)$ and $(2)\implies (1)$.

Now what remains is to show that $(1)\implies (3)$. And I have some problems to do so.

Consider a function $f\in L_{\mu}^p$ with $f=f\circ T$.

Now I have to show, that $f=\text{const}$:

How can I do that (using (1))?

I only can show that $f$ is constant almost surely: because $f$ is measurable and therefore from (1) it follows by (2) and the fact that $f=f\circ T$ even surely (i.e. especially almost surely) that $f$ is constant a.s.

But I do not manage it to show that $f$ is constant surely...

Can you please help me?

Comment: But I did not find it and maybe you can give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

In general, we may not have $f=f\circ T$ almost everywhere. Take indeed $N$ a non-empty invariant set of zero measure and replace $f$ by $g:=f\chi_N$, which satisfies $g=g\circ T$. Then when $f=c$ a.e. with $c\neq 0$, the function $g$ is not constant.